# iTunes versions installed

Tags: itunes, macos

When I click on iTunes update it shows there is a new version available.

[image: new]

However when I click on get it, it comes up with no updates available but shows 2 of the same versions downloaded? 11.2.1 !

[image]

How do I go about fixing that?

on MBA 10.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem #1.

I forgot that I did "Hide Updates" on iTunes (silly me).

By reactivating, it did show the bundle and allows me to update to 11.2.2 among all other updates in that bundle.

That still does not solve the part of having a duplicate update version showing foor 11.2.1.